# How do I prioritize performSelectorOnMainThread against NSConnection messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsrunloop

I have a lot of `NSURLConnection`s downloading.  They may not happen on the main thread.  When some of them finish, I call `performSelectorOnMainThread` for a separate singleton object.

I've used both forms of `performSelectorOnMainThread`, specifying the run loop mode (`NSDefaultRunLoopMode`) and not specifying it.  `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` is supposed to avoid `NSConnection` selectors, but the message still appears to be gated on them.  The indicated selector is not performed until after all the pending connections have been completely downloaded.

How do I prioritize `performSelectorOnMainThread` to happen before the others?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had another connection gating the one I had prioritized - performSelectorOnMainThread was not the problem.